# Slicing columns with .loc inconsistently

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'c': [1], 'd':[1], 'e':[1]})
df
```

I want to select `a,b,c,e` columns with .loc!
I find

```
l=df.loc[:, 'a':'c'].columns.to_list()
l+=['e']
df.loc[:, l]
```

But is there more convinient way? like

```
df.loc[:, ['a':'c', 'e']]
```

In real dataframe number of columns is much more than in this dataframe.

Comment: `df.loc[:, ['a','b','c','e']]` or `df.loc[:, [*'abce']]`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny In the real dataframe number of columns is much more than in this dataframe.

Comment: depending on your selection criteria [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) may come in handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
df2 = df.drop('d', axis=1)
```

Option 2:

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:3, 4]]
```

Option 3:

```
df2 = df.filter(regex='[^d]')
```

Option 4:

```
df2 = df[list(df.loc[:,'a':'c']) + ['e']]
```